# object Object output after appended text element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I'm fairly new to JavaScript and d3.js. I've created my chart and everything is running great on that end of things. However I'm trying to display some information in text in addtion to the graph which just shows montly sales total this year in comparison to the previous finacial year result.

The weird thing that I'm getting is that the text that is being displayed in the h2 is just showing `[object Object]` even though all the data is loading in fine when I've de-bugged it in firebug it shows this https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVbMT.png (I cant embedd as I dont have a high enough rep)
which is the correct data

This is the code that I've used for the text -

```
d3.csv("OrderValueToday.csv", function(today) { 
   console.log(today); 

   var totalSales = today

   svgLabel = d3.select("#label").append("h2")
     .text(totalSales)
});
```

The CSV that I'm getting already has the total sales today so there is no summing done on my end this is already been done for me when I get the data. The CSV is formatting like so

```
Today
20000
```

and this is the same pretty much for all the data that I have. If you could help me out fix this problem that would be fantastic as this the final thing that get this project done. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of things you're passing in an array containing an object. You just need to access the `Today` value.

```
d3.csv("OrderValueToday.csv", function(obj) { 
   var text = 'Total sales today = ';
   var totalSales = text + obj[0].Today;
   svgLabel = d3.select("#label").append("h2")
     .text(totalSales);
});
```

Comment: WOW! thanks so much working great now. Just a quick little question because now its showing `20000` is there a way that you can insert text before so for example `Total sales today = 20000` ?

Comment: Thanks ever so much got it working perfectly now,  your a champ!